# matplotlib histogram distributionplot, set x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I made a distributionplot, which looks like
[image]

My code right now is

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 7), dpi=160)
plt.hist(doc_lens, bins=10, color='navy')     
plt.title('Distribution of Document Word Counts', fontdict=dict(size=22))

outpath = os.path.join(self.outdir, "{}_distribution_document_word_counts.png".format(self.prefix))

plt.savefig(outpath)
plt.close()
```

`doc_lens` is a list with numbers.

I have 10 bins, now I would like to have the number 10 on the x-axis moved to where it belongs, how can I get that?

Comment: Where and why do you think that 10 belongs? Did you check what the resulting bins were from the `plt.hist` call?

Comment: i printend the number in each bin resulting in : [1.25991e+05 3.13000e+02 8.30000e+01 2.60000e+01 1.50000e+01 5.00000e+00
 3.00000e+00 3.00000e+00 1.00000e+00 3.00000e+00]. So I know the 10 on the x-as should be changed

Comment: Sorry: I meant the bin edges. What you are showing are the counts per bin. The bin edges (given that there are 10, and the highest value appears to 78 or so), would be something like [0, 7.8, 16.6, ...]. Could you check?

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to change the 10 on the x-axis. Nearly all values fall within the first bin, which is between 0 and ~8, which is what is shown here.

Comment: because i want to show that this bin represents 0 till 10 percent and not 0 till 7

Comment: Then it may be quicker (and easier) to scale your values (`doc_lens`) to the range [0, 100].

Answer (score 0):

```
    def make_plot(self, data, max, step, step_plot):
        plt.figure(figsize=(16, 7), dpi=160)

        plt.hist(data, bins=np.arange(0, max, step))
        plt.xticks(np.arange(0, max, step_plot))

        plt.text(750, 100, "Mean   : " + str(round(np.mean(data))))
        plt.text(750, 90, "Median : " + str(round(np.median(data))))
        plt.text(750, 80, "Stdev   : " + str(round(np.std(data))))
        plt.text(750, 70, "1%ile    : " + str(round(np.quantile(data, q=0.01))))
        plt.text(750, 60, "99%ile  : " + str(round(np.quantile(data, q=0.99))))

        plt.gca().set(ylabel='Number of Documents', xlabel='Document Word Count')
        plt.title('Distribution of Document Word Counts', fontdict=dict(size=22))

        outpath = os.path.join(self.outdir,
                               "{}_{}_distribution_words_in_documents.png".format(self.prefix, max))

        plt.savefig(outpath)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).